# Make major mode be used by default for new files in directory

Tags: major-mode

I forget to enter `sh-mode` when I create new shell scripts in `~/.local/bin`, so I want emacs to do this automatically. Because I have an advice set up to make them executable, this will have the effect of also marking them executable automatically.

I tried creating this `.dir-locals.el` file in the directory:

```
((nil . ((magic-fallback-mode-alist . (("^$" . sh-mode))))))
```

but although it asked me whether to apply the "risky" file-local variable `magic-fallback-mode-alist`, it did not work - the new buffer was still using fundamental-mode.

Comment: Do your scripts have an extension? If so, you can associates the extension with `sh-mode` in `auto-mode-alist`. For example: `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.sh\\'" . sh-mode))`. This should already be the default, but if you are using another extension, you can set it this way (this will apply globally though, not just to files in that directory.

Comment: `normal-mode` calls `(set-auto-mode)` and `(hack-local-variables)` in that order (as indeed it needs to in order for directory local specifications to match on the major mode). This is why your `.dir-locals.el` does not have the desired effect.

Comment: About "I have an advice set up to make them executable, this will have the effect of also marking them executable automatically.", if you have this in your config `(add-hook 'after-save-hook #'executable-make-buffer-file-executable-if-script-p)`, any file that begins with `#!`, example `#!/bin/sh`, will be automatically made an executable when you save the file. Adding that hash-bang will also automatically set the correct sh-mode (correct flavor of sh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`auto-insert-mode` should do this for you.

1. Follow the instructions at the beginning of the file you get when you type <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-library` `autoinsert`, i.e., add `(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'auto-insert)` to your initialization file.
2. Make sure you have `("/bin/.*[^/]\\'" . "Shell-Script mode magic number")` in the variable `auto-insert-alist`. This should already be the case.

Comment: Oh neat. I have uses for this for sure :)

Comment: @Tobias I never heard of `auto-insert-mode`! :) At a quick glance, it looks like [`header2`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/header2.el) package. Is it?